# Multi-dimensional array and for loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So I have some data that is being pulled from my database table.

The data just records a date and time instance i.e. the flag `1, 10`.

[`1` = `Monday`, `2` = `Tuesday,` ...] and the `10` being `10:00:00am` which is shortened to just `10`.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th> 
        <th>Thursday</th> 
        <th>Friday</th> 
        <th>Saturday</th> 
        <th>Sunday</th> 
    </tr> 
    <tr></tr> 
</table>
```

I want to be able to add the data into a two-dimensional array i.e. `[10][3]` for `11am` on thursday (`11-1` place in the array and `4-1` place in the array)

How is the best way of going about this? I am quite stuck as in how to implement it.

Comment: I want to be able to loop in the table through each instance from [0][0] to [0][7] across in days and all the way to [24][0] in hours

Comment: I'm trying to understand the array structure you're talking about and can't quite grasp it based on your explanation. Can you give an example of the data you have, and the output that you're looking for. Like, initial and final products.

Comment: Please reword your question with examples of expected results.

Comment: I am trying to make a calendar that displays the dates from monday to sunday in 7 columns along with the times 12am until 11pm in corrosoponding rows so that the table shows a full week schedule with 24 hours per day and 7 hours per week. I am trying to pass a date, time down in a two dimensional array and then read it on the page to place it in the corrosponding positon that it should be in. How can I best achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
      <th></th>
     <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
     <th>Wednesday</th> 
     <th>Thursday</th> 
     <th>Friday</th> 
      <th>Saturday</th> 
     <th>Sunday</th> 
  </tr> 
  <?php
  for ($i=0; $i<24; $i++) { // loop for hours
  ?>
 <tr>
    <th><?= $i."-".($i+1)."h" ?></th>
    <?php
  for ($j=1; $j<=7; $j++) { // loop for days
  ?>
    <td></td>
  <?php
    } // loop days
    ?>
 </tr> 
 <?php
} // loop hours
 ?>
 
</table>
```